Trouble signing in with “Windows Hello.” It doesn't ask me to input password or PIN
I have an issue with Duo security authentication in Firefox (same issue with Chrome as well). Every time I request to sign in though “Windows Hello,” I get the below modal dialog:

I am not sure how to sign in. It doesn't ask me to input password or PIN. I already set up my “Windows Hello” PIN in settings.
What might be the issue?

Update: A translation of the non-English (Japanese) text from the screenshot is as follows:

Windows Security
Making sure it's you
Please sign in to duosecurity.com.
This request comes from Firefox, published by Mozilla Corporation.

Original Japanese text from the screenshot follows:

Windows セキュリティ
本人確認をしています
duosecurity.com にサインインしてください。
この要求は、Mozilla Corporationによって発行された Firefox から取得されました。


You will have to provide an English translation

@Ramhound It asks me to sign in duosecurity.com that's all

Have you signed in with Duo Security? Have you checked that site for instructions regarding this issue?

@user366875 - I still cannot read the rest of the prompt

@Ramhound You can find the prompt from here minus the "touch the security key" part.

@music2myear No, signing in with Duo is the point of my question.

See my reply. I'm working with Duo for living. Feel free to ask more ( in this threat ). I don't promise to answer soon thought, as I'm not a regular here

@Netan What "threat" are you referring to?

Cisco Duo does not support Windows Hello for "Windows RDP" app.
Boot in safe mode, delete Duo app, reboot.
Set a password. Then reinstall Duo.

For Duo Authentication for Windows Logon (RDP) and otherwise, Duo does not support Windows Hello at this time. This includes logging in to Windows using a PIN instead of a password.

https://help.duo.com/s/article/3762?language=es

Bruh, it turns out that I forgot to set up Windows Hello login in the first place. I was able to successfully set up by following instructions in this page.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Oh, that's for passwordless, not RDP. haha

Answers should include any steps necessary to solve the issue. Links are just for reference. Please add the necessary information. See how to answer
